# Python walking a directory in an attempt to manually create combined PDF

Tags: python, csv, pdf

I have a folder of PDF's and I am using Python to 1) parse info from them 2) output info into .csv 3) copy into an "output" folder and finally *4) I would then like to combine PDFs(manual Adobe command) of the output folder such that it is in identical order to the output csv.  I was assuming if I used Python sorted(files) to loop, the order would match when I sort the filedir, but alas...

I attempted to use sorted(directory) to walk the files in order...

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in sorted(files):
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            with open (os.path.join(subdir, file), "r") as myfile:
                foo(file)

def foo(myFile):
    #get info and append to csv
    shutil.copyfile(myFile,outputFolder+myFile)
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: So the problem is that when you run the "manual Adobe command" that your pdfs don't get concatenated in order, is that it? Which "command" is that? And if so, please post a more complete version of your code (but keep it minimal, like you did): include the definition of `outputFolder` and fix the error in calling `foo`.